# assignment from incompatible pointer type using a typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Usually when I get this kind of error message, it means that the struct is hidden from the code and because of that I cannot use the struct's variables directly.

In this case the struct is defined in the same C file.

I pasted the C file at http://bpaste.net/show/224777/

at line 330 I have the following code:

```
TrackBoxWidget *track_box_widget_new(GtkWidget *track_data_widget,GVariant *audio_in_devices) {
// can add more parameters here
TrackBoxWidget *widget = g_object_new(TRACK_BOX_WIDGET_TYPE,"audio_in_devices", audio_in_devices,NULL);
/*LINE 330*/    widget->track_data_widget=track_data_widget;
...
```

as you can see I;'m tryuing to set the track_data_widget variable inside widget that is TrackBoxWidget typedef. and somehow i still get this error.

any ideas?

Comment: member `track_data_widget` is type `TrackDataWidget`, but parameter `track_data_widget` is type `GtkWidget`?

Comment: whoops :) thanks for notifying me. checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left-hand side of your assignment you have `widget->track_data_widget`, a member of `TrackBoxWidget` (aka `struct _track_box_widget`), of type `TrackDataWidget*`.

On the right-hand side of your assignment you have `track_data_widget`, the parameter of the `track_box_widget_new` function, of type `GtkWidget*`. Since the two pointers are of different types, a direct assignment between them is not allowed without a cast.